# Having a AWS User Pool user stay signed in

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have setup up user pools in my ios app and regesitered a user. I also am testing if the user signs in correctly (still working on this). But I think they do. But when I rebuild my app on the device a second time my pool and user are empty.

Does that mean they aren't signed in? Or do I need to have the user pool remember the device for this to work? Thanks.

Comment: Yo have to to store the sessionID in the preferences.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of that in an answer I can mark accept too? I am using the code from the attached and  pool.delegate = self; code website - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-ios.html